# One Dot vs Two Dots to import file

Tags: paths, import, subfiles, directory

Sometimes I see one dot (like: `\subfile{./chapters/file.tex}`) and sometimes two (like: `\graphicspath{{figures/}{../figures/}}`) while importing a file. Can someone clarify which is used when?

Comment: On Windows, `.` = current folder, `..` = parent folder.

Comment: @Cicada Okay so if the path is C:\\Users\Name\Desktop\FOLDER where the files are stored, and my current folder is Book (located inside FOLDER) Then parent means FOLDER right? (Would I write something like \subfile{../Book/file_inside_FOLDER.tex} to access a file inside FOLDER?)

Comment: Do an experiment with `dir .` and `dir ..` at your command prompt. `.` means "from here", and `./somefolder` means "from here, go down one level, into /somefolder". `../someotherfolder` means "go up one level, and then down into /someotherfolder".

Comment: @Cicada Got you, thanks!

Comment: Have a look here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008829/what-does-a-dot-mean-in-a-url-path